# Government without opposition

Tags: government, political-theory, political-system

What would happen if a ruling government has no opposition? What would be its effect to the people and development? Am referring to a scenario where the opponent the president or governor has been taken in to work with the government .

Comment: Hi mykey. I believe "what if" scenarios are outside the scope of this Q&A. Maybe you could re-phrase it to an actual situation that occurred before or is occurring.

Comment: Unlikely to happen. In Italy when the winning party agreed to rule with its main enemy, some other party disagreed so there still was some opposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been 'goverments of national unity' that include most (and sometimes all) parties. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_unity_government for examples. As of "what would happen" - well, nothing special, they simply are able to get the governing done, work together until the 'unity' fades, and then it's back to business as usual.

And of course, there have been many cases with single-organization governments - too many to count, but some periods of USSR and current North Korea can be examples of a ruling government that has no opposition, if that fits your criteria.